# Save String to Array using SharedPreferences for Android (Eclipse)

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, string

I am trying to save a string 'reftext' to the first element of an array 'savedabc[]' using SharedPreferences. My variables are declared as below.

```
private EditText reftext;
private static SharedPreferences savedabc;
private static EditText[] savedabc;
```

Here is the 'Save' method:

```
    public void onSaveClick(View view) {
    SharedPreferences savedabc = getSharedPreferences("SavedABC", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savedabc.edit();
    editor.putString(savedabc[0], reftext);
    editor.commit();
}
```

However, this gives me the following error: "The method putString(String, String) in the type SharedPreferences.Editor is not applicable for the arguments (EditText, EditText)".

Could anyone help with this please?

Many thanks.

Comment: 2 variables with the same name... not good. Also, you are passing in 2 `EditTexts` when what it wants is 2 `Strings`.

Comment: Ah yes I've changed the variable names, thanks. So what would be a better way of doing this using editor?

Comment: You need to extract the strings from your `EditTexts` using something along the lines of `editText.getText()`. That will give you a `String` which you can put into `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Ok I can see that working for the 'reftext' string but for the array as well?

Comment: This can be help to you : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences